# Rails use multiple query in single query for importing csv file data

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

How to pass araay data in IN operator query.

```
data = ["055226", "000879", "069889", "078720", "078764"] //use array data in query statements IN operator

file_data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT t1.user_id, t2.dept_id, t1.price, 
t3.first_name, t3.last_name
      FROM price_table t1
      INNER JOIN user_branch_table t2
        on t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
      INNER JOIN user_deatils_table t3
        on t1.user_id = t3.user_id
      where t1.user_id in (#{data}) and now() between t2.start_dt and t2.end_dt").first
```

I have tried with different ways, but didn't get proper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below should work:

```
    file_data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SELECT t1.user_id, t2.dept_id, t1.price, 
t3.first_name, t3.last_name
      FROM price_table t1
      INNER JOIN user_branch_table t2
        on t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
      INNER JOIN user_deatils_table t3
        on t1.user_id = t3.user_id
      where t1.user_id in (#{data.join(',')}) and now() between t2.start_dt and t2.end_dt").first
```

> The above won't work for the string inputs, The below should work for string inputs

```
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
      ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["SELECT 
        t1.user_id, t2.dept_id, t1.price, 
        t3.first_name, t3.last_name
        FROM price_table t1
        INNER JOIN user_branch_table t2
        on t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
        INNER JOIN user_deatils_table t3
        on t1.user_id = t3.user_id
        where t1.user_id in (?) and now() between t2.start_dt and t2.end_dt", data])).first
```

Comment: thanks for responding, a 2nd one is working, but i need to add or append in  new price of file data while displaying on screen 'file_data'. I am getting issue in that.

Comment: Now, I am getting data from db by using  `file_data = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(
 ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, ["SELECT 
        t1.user_id, t2.dept_id, t1.price, t3.first_name, t3.last_name FROM price_table t1 INNER JOIN user_branch_table t2 on t1.user_id = t2.user_id INNER JOIN user_deatils_table t3 on t1.user_id = t3.user_id where t1.user_id in (?) and now() between t2.start_dt and t2.end_dt", data]))` but i have another data to add in file data at the end of data of each record. `file_new_price{"new_price"=>"900", new_price"=>"960"}`  how to append this?

Comment: Ok, I get from above records like `file_data =  [{"user_id"=>"101", "dept_id"=>"01", "price"=>"950", "first_name"=>"ajit", "last_name"=>"shinde"}, {"user_id"=>"102", "dept_id"=>"02", "price"=>"950", "first_name"=>"vikas", "last_name"=>"patil"}, {"user_id"=>"103", "dept_id"=>"03", "price"=>"950", "first_name"=>"rohit", "last_name"=>"patel"}]` this is db record and i want to add new_price each record at the end of data from `csv_data =  [{"user_id"=>"101", "date"=>"2020-08-13", "new_price"=>"1000"}, {"user_id"=>"102", "date"=>"2020-08-13", "new_price"=>"800"}]`

Comment: in query `.first` is not working in second query. given only one record. and i have tried to fetch every user of recent recorde.